# Get list of all commits (summaries) with the per-file diff/patch

Tags: git

I have a simple Git repo with non-branching commits in the master branch. I want to produce a listing of all commits over time with message (like `git log` produces) but for each I want to see the delta patch between that commit and the previous for each file (like `git diff` produces when explicitly fed the adjacent commit values).

Is this something I can produce with git directly, or do I just need to scrape the output of `git log` and use a script to feed the rolling values to `git diff`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
git log -p
```

The `-p` option tells `git log` to output a *patch* for each commit.

Answer (score 2):

Does `git log -u` suffice?

Filler here because answer was too short.

Comment: Thanks; though `-u` and `-p` are the same (as is `--patch`) @Greg gets the accept mark for using the slightly-more-standard flag.

Answer (score 1):

#### Logs for Current Branch

If you want the logs with patches just for the current branch, you can use `git log --patch` to view each entry with its associated diff format.

#### Logs for Everything

The git-log(1) command also takes a list of commits, so you could walk the tree and see *all* the commits in your repository with `git log --patch $(git rev-parse --all)`.

#### See Also

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History